# AndroidRuntime Error - java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, json, android-layout, android-intent

I am learning android on my free time, I'm trying to collect data from a `MySQL DB` on android using `Json`, but I have a problem handling the threads.

Here is main Class

```
package com.esoftarena.demotest;

public class DemoTestActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    /* Called when the activity is first created. */

    Intent intent;
    Button home,repot, settings, remind, savedata;
    EditText lecdeliver, lecbunked, comment;
    TextView showpercent, showremark;
    InputStream is = null;
    static String json = "";
    String url = "";
    int id = 3, nodeliver = 0 , nobunk = 0;
    JSONArray bunkInfo = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        home = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnHome);
        repot = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnReport);
        settings = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSettings);
        remind = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRemind);
        savedata = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsave);

        lecdeliver = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtlecdeliver);
        lecbunked = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtlecbunked);
        comment = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtnote);

        showpercent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblshowpercent);
        showremark = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblshowremark);

        home.setOnClickListener(this);
        repot.setOnClickListener(this);
        settings.setOnClickListener(this);
        remind.setOnClickListener(this);
        savedata.setOnClickListener(this);

        url = "http://www.test.com/getbunk.php?getreuslt=true&userno="+id;

        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts
            bunkInfo = json.getJSONArray("bunkinfo");

            // looping through All Contacts
            for(int i = 0; i < bunkInfo.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = bunkInfo.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                nodeliver = nodeliver + c.getInt("cl_delivered");
                nobunk = nobunk + c.getInt("cl_bunked");

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        showpercent.setText(nodeliver);
        showremark.setText(nobunk);

        //Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome to page.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onClick(View clicked) {
        if(clicked == home) {
            //recipes = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.recipes);
            Toast.makeText(this, "You have Clicked Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(DemoTestActivity.this, DemoTestHome.class);
            DemoTestActivity.this.startActivity(i);
            //Intent i = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, RecipeMethodActivity.class);
           // SearchActivity.this.startActivity(i);
         }else if(clicked == repot){
             Toast.makeText(this, "You have Clicked Report", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             Intent i = new Intent(DemoTestActivity.this, DemoTestReport.class);
             DemoTestActivity.this.startActivity(i);
         }else if(clicked == settings ){
             Toast.makeText(this, "You have Clicked Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             Intent i = new Intent(DemoTestActivity.this, DemoTestSettings.class);
             DemoTestActivity.this.startActivity(i);
         }else if(clicked == remind ){
             Toast.makeText(this, "You have Clicked Remind Me", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             Intent i = new Intent(DemoTestActivity.this, DemoTestRemind.class);
             DemoTestActivity.this.startActivity(i);
         }else if(clicked == savedata ){
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.test.com/addbunk.php");

            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("add_new_bunk", "true"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userno", "3"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lec_delivered", lecdeliver.getText().toString()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lec_bunked", lecbunked.getText().toString()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comment", comment.getText().toString()));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

                //content = response.getEntity().getContent();
               // Toast.makeText(this, content , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            try {
                JSONObject userObject = new JSONObject(json);
                String msg = userObject.getString("msg");
                Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch(Exception ex){
                //don't forget this
            }

         }

    }
}
```

Here is JsonParser

```
package com.esoftarena.demotest;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

And Here is LogCat List

```
02-04 17:41:33.296: D/AndroidRuntime(324): Shutting down VM
02-04 17:41:33.296: W/dalvikvm(324): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
02-04 17:41:33.386: E/AndroidRuntime(324): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 17:41:33.386: E/AndroidRuntime(324): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.esoftarena.demotest/com.esoftarena.demotest.DemoTestActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
02-04 17:41:33.386: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
02-04 17:41:33.386: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-04 17:41:33.386: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-04 17:41:33.386: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-04 17:41:33.386: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-04 17:41:33.386: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-04 17:41:33.386: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-04 17:41:33.386: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 17:41:33.386: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-04 17:41:33.386: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-04 17:41:33.386: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-04 17:41:33.386: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-04 17:41:33.386: E/AndroidRuntime(324): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
02-04 17:41:33.386: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at com.esoftarena.demotest.DemoTestActivity.onCreate(DemoTestActivity.java:60)
02-04 17:41:33.386: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-04 17:41:33.386: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
02-04 17:41:33.386: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  ... 11 more
02-04 17:41:59.676: I/Process(324): Sending signal. PID: 324 SIG: 9
```

Here is XML FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblwelcome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/welcome"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnHome"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/home" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnReport"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/reports" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSettings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/settings" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRemind"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/remindme" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >








        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbldelivered"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lecdelivered"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />





        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblbunked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.05"
            android:text="@string/lecturebunk"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >




        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtlecdeliver"
            android:layout_width="127dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>



        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtlecbunked"
            android:layout_width="132dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >




        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblpercent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.41"
            android:text="@string/curpercent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblshowpercent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.41"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblremark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.74"
            android:text="@string/lblremark"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblshowremark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.74"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblyournote"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.29"
            android:text="@string/note"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />




        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtnote"
            android:layout_width="189dp"
            android:layout_height="78dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.10"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress|textShortMessage" />

    </LinearLayout>




    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnsave"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/save" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: `showpercent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblshowpercent);` line causing problem make sure it's TextView in xml layout

Comment: Please post your main.xml layout file code.

Comment: Here you go. http://pastebin.com/Uc0gqE6J

Comment: do a clean build of your project...

Comment: Thank you everyone for your effort. i found the solution. if forgot to typecast two variable to string before setting as text.
 

    'showpercent.setText(Integer.toString(nodeliver));
    showremark.setText(Integer.toString(nobunk));'

That worked for me. Again thank you all.